# How to select two or more element in SQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Please note I'm a beginner in SQL and PHP and I search =every where but didn't found anything useful
I want to select two data from the following table.

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe |
| 2 | John |

my code

```
else if($_SESSION['name']=='Joe')
```

I tried use this syntax but didn't **work =='Joe', 'John'**, **==('Joe', 'John')**
Please help me

Comment: _"my code"_ - what is that PHP else-if supposed to have to do with the database query? And what is the column actually named now, `name` or `work`?

Comment: `WHERE name = 'Joe' OR name = 'John'` would be one way, `WHERE name IN ('Joe', 'John')` another. Both options that most _beginner tutorials_ on the matter should be able to explain to you, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select name from table where name in ('joe','john')
```